# Should gpg be a synonym of gnupg?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Recently I saw that there are several PGP/GPG related tags:

- [openpgp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/openpgp)
- [pgp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/pgp)
- [gnupg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnupg)
- [gpg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gpg)

According to my knowledge gpg is the short form of [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/). The executable file is also called `gpg`. So I think [gpg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gpg) should be a synonym of [gnupg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnupg). What do you think?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's a good spot. I have merged the `gpg` posts into `gnupg`.